# Access JSON array via PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to access a JSON attribute which contains an array of strings, using PowerShell

**JSON**

```
{
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "teamName": "Team A",
  "securityGroups": [{
      "name": "Security Group 1",
      "members:": ["abc@mail.com", "def@mail.com", "ghi@mail.com"]
    },
    {
    "name": "Securiy Group 2",
    "members:": ["123@mail.com", "456@mail.com", "789@mail.com"]
  }]
}
```

**PowerShell**

```
$json = Get-Content 'test.json' | ConvertFrom-Json 

ForEach($group in $json.securityGroups)
{
    Write-Host "Team: $($group.name)"

    ForEach($member in $group.members)
    {
        Write-Host "Member: $($member)"
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Team: Security Group 1
Team: Securiy Group 2
```

As you can see, only the name of the security group (**securityGroup.name**) gets shown. I'm unable to access the **securityGroups.members** node, which contains an array of strings (containing emails). My goal is to store this list of strings and loop through them.

When I check to see how the $json object looks like in PS, I get the following:

```
PS C:\Users\XYZ> $json

id                                   teamName securityGroups                                                                                         
--                                   -------- --------------                                                                                         
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Team A   {@{name=Security Group 1; members:=System.Object[]}, @{name=Securiy Group 2; members:=System.Object[]}}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You almost got me... There is a colon in the `members:` key, meaning if this is correct (which I doubt), you will need to do: `ForEach($member in $group.'members:')`

Comment: @iRon Can't believe I missed the extra colon, thanks. I've left out the colon in the attribute name, but oddly enough still get nothing when I run my code.

EDIT: nvm, had to refresh my $json attribute. The extra colon ended up being the culprit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$json = Get-Content 'test.json' | ConvertFrom-Json 

ForEach ($group in $json.securityGroups)
{
    Write-Host "Team: $($group.name)"

    ForEach ($member in $group."members:")
    {
        Write-Host "Member: $($member)"
    }
}
```

You haven't noted that member key contains a colon at the end. Otherwise it will give you wrong result.